# Can't render a collection of data successfully fetched from firebase with react hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am fetching a docs collection from firebase and then passing it to a state so react re-renders it whenever it gets updated.

```
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    const fetchPosts = () => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('posts').get()
            .then(snap => {
                snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    setPosts([...posts, doc.data()])
                    console.log(doc.data())
                })
            })
    }



    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts()
    }, [])
```

I also passed this state to other components so they also re-render with updated state

But react is only rendering the first doc of collection and giving error in console: 'every child should have a unique key prop'. My each doc object has a unique id inside and i am passing this as key with each post

```
    <div className="posts section">
        {posts.map(post=>{
            return <Link to={'/posts/'+post.id}><PostCard  post={post} key={post.id} /></Link>
        })}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not recommend using document/array data as a key, as subsequent renders can be inefficient. A lovely React function can take care of the unique key problem.

```
<div className="posts section">
    {React.Children.toArray(
      posts.map(post => {
        return (
          <Link to={"/posts/" + post.id}>
           <PostCard post={post} />
          </Link>
        );
      })
    )}
</div>
```

Another problem you may be having is useEffect MUST be synchronous.  you may want to explicitly declare fetchPosts as asynchronous.  I use the following to process the querySnapshot:

```
  return query
    .get() //get the resulting filtered query results
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      return Promise.resolve(
        querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          return {
            ...doc.data(),
            Id: doc.id,
            ref: doc.ref
          };
        })
      );
    })
```

The best reason for the .map is you cannot guarantee the *last* "setPosts" has actually completed before your next loop, so your state ("posts", in this case), may be stale.

So, net of all of this, my pattern would be:

```
   const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    const fetchPosts = () => {
        return firebase.firestore().collection('posts').get()
        .then(snap => {
            snap.docs.map(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data())
                return {
                   ...doc.data(),
                   id: doc.id,
                   ref: doc.ref
                };
            })
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const newPosts = await fetchPosts();
            setPosts(newPosts);
        })();
    }, [])

    //[etc, etc]

    return
    //[etc, etc]

        <div className="posts section">
        {React.Children.toArray(
            posts.map(post=>{
                return <Link to={'/posts/'+post.id}><PostCard  post={post} key={post.id} /></Link>
            })
        }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the key prop to the `Link` component.

**Example**

```
const fetchPosts = () => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("posts")
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        let docs = [];
        snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
            docs.push(doc.data());
        });
        setPosts( prevState => [...prevState, ...docs]);
      });
  };
```

```
<div className="posts section">
    {posts.map(post => {
    return (
        <Link key={post.id} to={"/posts/" + post.id}>
         <PostCard post={post} />
        </Link>
    );
    })}
</div>
```

Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: nope, it didn't.. same problem. still rendering only first fetched document.

Comment: Could you create a sandbox and add your code there?

Comment: adding key in the link removed the console error.. but no effect on rendering.  Weired thing is all fetched posts are console logging fine... but they are not being rendered by react

Comment: Try the updated code. Use call back to update the state.